# Problem exchanging auth code for token, Go OAuth2

Tags: go, oauth-2.0

i am having problems exchanging auth code for a token. Have anyone else come across a similar error before? I am very new to OAuth2, having to learn it from scratch and applying it in a couple days, sadly there are noone at my firm who are familiar with OAuth2.

package main

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "golang.org/x/oauth2"
    "log"
    "math/rand"
    "net/http"
)

var (
    oAuth2Config= &oauth2.Config{
        ClientID:     "<client_id>",
        ClientSecret: "<client_secret>",
        Endpoint: oauth2.Endpoint{
            AuthURL:   "https://oauth2.provider.no/auth",
            TokenURL:  "https://oauth2.provider.no/token",
            AuthStyle: 1,
        },
        RedirectURL: "<redirect_uri>",
        Scopes:      nil,
    }
    resourceServerURL           = "https://api.provider.no"
    resourceServerPathCustomers = "/gapi/v1/customers"
    resourceServerPathCases     = "/gapi/v1/cases"
    resourceServerPathAlarms    = "/gapi/v1/alarms"
    resourceServerPathCIS       = "/gapi/v1/cis"
    // tokenChan                   = make(chan *oauth2.Token) // we could possibly send a token here and continue using it.
    oAuth2State = randomString(14)
)

func randomString(length int) string {
    str := "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWYZ0123456789"
    generatedString := make([]rune, length)
    for i := 0; i < len(generatedString); i++ {
        generatedString[i] = rune(str[rand.Intn(len(str))])
    }
    return string(generatedString)
}

func main() {

    http.HandleFunc("/", handleCallback)
    if err := http.ListenAndServe(":8082", nil); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

}

func handleCallback(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    _ = Auth2Config.AuthCodeURL(oAuth2State)

    if state := r.FormValue("state"); state != OAuth2State {
        fmt.Println("state is not valid")
        return
    }

    token, err := oAuth2Config.Exchange(oauth2.NoContext, r.FormValue("code"))
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        return
    }

    fmt.Println(token.AccessToken)
}
```

Error:

```
    2020/03/16 15:49:30 oauth2: cannot fetch token: 400
Response: {"error_description":"Missing grant_type parameter value","error":"invalid_reques│
t"}
```

Comment: [Exchange sets the grant_type parameter correctly](https://github.com/golang/oauth2/blob/aaccbc9213/oauth2.go#L215). You must be dealing with a non-standard server.

Comment: @CeriseLimón thank you for pointing that out, i forgot to remove that during my testing phase. However removing it does nothing to solve the problem.

Peter, I have had this conclusion aswell, however the company's developer keep telling me that i'm in the wrong here.

Comment: No i have no other handler during this testing phase, Auth2Config.AuthCodeURL(oAuth2State) was a mistake that i left in the code i published here. r.FormValue("code") is the auth code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The server was not standard, so had to customize.